# Question on heat

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

Is this statement correct?
The oxygen and nitrogen molecules in a box has equal average kinetic energy but the oxygen molecules are faster.
I am not sure because I thought oxygen molecules should move slower because they are heavier.
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you unsure? As you say the oxygen atom is more massive. You have already stated your answer. The statement appears to be false.

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic energy is related to both the mass *and* velocity of a particle through the equation $T= \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ where $T$ is the kinetic energy of the particle.  So you are correct that the oxygen particles *will* likely move slower, because they are more massive, but as long as the product of the mass and the velocity squared of the oxygen particles (on average) equals the product of the mass and the velocity squared of the nitrogen particles (on average), the particles will have the same average kinetic energy.

You can convince yourself that this will be the case, because the average kinetic energy of a substance is, by definition, its temperature.  Even if your nitrogen and oxygen initially begin at different temperatures (and therefore different average kinetic energies), they will exchange energy through collisions until both species of gas have reached thermodynamic equilibrium, and therefore the same temperature, and same average kinetic energy.   Think about it:  when you put an ice cube into a cup of hot tea, the ice cube heats up, melts, and then heats up some more, while the tea cools down, until the final mixture has a uniform temperature.  If you take a cold soda, and put it outside on a warm summer day, it will warm up until it reaches the same temperature as the air around it. Your oxygen/nitrogen mixture is no different.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simple point is Kinetic energy depends upon the mass and the square of velocity. Even if the mass of the object in this case molecule is relatively greater than that of the other molecule, as long as the velocity is greater enough to balance the average kinetic energy, it will be uniform. 
To put it simply K.E = 1/2*(m*v^2).